# Element Animation/Transition Between Multiple Views not between activity or fragment

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am new to android animation/transition and I want to make one animation as shown below:

How should I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple choice :

- use [`TransitionManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions):

there is two type of transition you can work with this library

1. use `TransitionManager.go()`. in this scenario you should create two `scene` and switch between these two scene. **all needed animation will handle by Transition Manager**.for more info read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#CreateScene) link

example:

```
 Scene aScene;
 Scene anotherScene;

 // Create the scene root for the scenes in this app
 sceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);

 // Create the scenes
 aScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.a_scene, this);
 anotherScene =
    Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.another_scene, this);
 //transition from root scene to another scene
 TransitionManager.go(anotherScene);
```

2. use `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView)`.in this scenario you can set beginDelayTransition on the `paren` and all direct child will animate on layout attribute change.for more info read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#NoScenes) link

example:

```
// Get the root view and create a transition
rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mFade = new Fade(Fade.IN);

// Start recording changes to the view hierarchy
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, mFade);

// change in one of rootView childs
childView.setWidth(100);

// When the system redraws the screen to show this update,
// the framework will animate the addition as a fade in
```

- use [`MotionLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout). for more info read link.
- in your case you can use `viewPager` too. you can create two fragment **first with keyboard** for enter price and **second an input "for"**, the rest of views keep in parent. then switch `viewPager` between this two fragment on click price in header, also you need to fade in/out header price and "cancel" button base on current fragment.you will see something like your gif.

Comment: thank you for your answer. How can I add a transition to fragment inside view pager? and how to handle communication between fragments and parent fragments?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try [Motion Editor](https://riggaroo.dev/getting-started-with-the-motion-editor-in-android-studio-4-0/)

for more deep study try some video tutorials on Youtube.